# Why is one day in a discrete math problem taken as 100,000 seconds?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have the following problem description and I am given several functions:

"What is the largest n for which one can solve within a day using an algorithm that requires f (n) bit operations, where each bit operation is carried out in 10−11 seconds, with these functions f (n)?"

I saw a solution where one day was taken as 100,000 seconds when there are exactly 86,400 seconds. Is such an approach correct? If so, why?

Comment: Rather strange! In complexity theory, often only rough magnitudes are of interest, but this "approximation" is very rough.

Comment: Perhaps because (with that approximation) you could say that you could perform $10^5/10^{-11} = 10^{16}$ operations per day, showing you just how bad (say) exponential run time is? So if the program needed $10^{17}$ operations, you'd be waiting for over a week!

Answer (score -1):

The approximation is not so bad.

Also, what makes you think that a day has 86400 seconds? Some days - where leap seconds occur - have 86401. Consider that the number of 'days in a month' is even less constant.

Save yourself a lot of bother, and pick constants which is are easily defined, and easily divided.